# Google PHP API library example: user-example: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: php, firefox, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-url-shortener

Running Windows 7 Ultimate / Apache 2.4.9 / PHP 5.5.11 / FireFox 29.

When I try running the Google PHP API example [user-example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php) (using FireFox) I am able to connect and receive the approval page for the `URL Shortener`. However, when I click on the `Accept` button I receive the message:

> "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost"

`netstat` showed that only Apache was listening on port 80. So, thinking that this might be a call-back issue, I ran a REST script (using the same credentials) that did pretty much the same thing, i.e. queried OAuth etc. **This worked successfully**.

> NB: IE11 fails at the same point with a "This page can’t be displayed"
>   message, the offending URL being `https://accounts.google.com.`

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the $redirect_uri is set correctly?

Comment: I believe so: when the same parameters are used in a googleapi REST script that requires a call-back everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue, much to my chagrin.

With all the other URI's in the example being "https://" I inadvertently set the call-back's URI to

> `https://localhost/etc`

The solution was to set the call-back's URI to an 'http', i.e.

> `http://localhost/etc`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, and its to big for a comment but try this

Changing the following PHP.ini settings:

1. Uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll - necessary for 'https' URLs;
2. Set the time-zone. Google is fussy about times, so this might have affected the outcome.

Comment: This be me i.e. my solution to problem #1  8) I am now on to problem #2